# jQuery ajax request to return data and repeat

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

**jQuery code**

```
var seconds = 6;
var timeout = seconds * 1000;

function request() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getdata.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // check if json data is returned from the php script


        // somehow put the returned json data into a variable or return it?
        // this is where my problem is


    });
}

function doLoop() {
    request() // execute the ajax request to get data from database

    var items = // the returned json data from function request()
    var count = items.length;
    var repeat = count * timeout;

    $(items).each(function(idx, text) {
        $("#text").queue(function(next) {
            $(this).html(text);
            next();
        }).delay(timeout);
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    doLoop();
}, repeat);
```

**The problem**

The problem is that I can't get the ajax call to return the json data so I can put it into an array.
This results in not being able to count how many items there are in the array and calculate the interval for the looping procedure.

What I wish to accomplish is a repeating procedure, using setInterval, that:

1. gets data from database with function `request`
2. put returned json data from `request` into array `items`
3. determine amount of items in array using `var count = items.length`
4. determine delay for `setInterval` using `var repeat = timeout * count`
5. process the array by displaying the items within, one at the time (this part works)
6. after processing the entire array, return to step 1 to refresh the data. (should be no problem with setInterval)

Comment: How is your `getdata.php` file? How do you send back the json data?

Comment: if the `data` that you get in the `done` function is a string, you can use `JSON.parse(data)` to parse it. But don't forget to put the results in a variable (`var x = JSON.parse(data)`)

Comment: After pulling the data from the database I `json_encode` it.

Comment: Does your console.log(data) display correctly your data?

Comment: console.log(data) returns correct json data from the PHP script

Comment: NOTE: you need to declare `var repeat` outside of the function

Comment: @denniz I've added a new answer with the right code and the use of promises. Let me know if it feets your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var seconds = 6;
var timeout = seconds * 1000;
var repeat;

function doLoop() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getdata.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var items = data;
        var count = items.length;
        repeat = count * timeout;

        $(items).each(function(idx, text) {
            $("#text").queue(function(next) {
                $(this).html(text);
                next();
            }).delay(timeout);
        });
        setTimeout(doLoop, repeat);
// use setTimeout() instead to make sure the 
//script won't trigger before finishing the previous job.
    });
}

$(document).ready(doLoop);
```

Comment: Reading this made sense. Implementing it solved 2 problems at once. The main problem of getting the json data and repeating the loop and additionally the problem of showing the first item in the array at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn the logic around. What you want is to start the request and when that's done you pass the returned data to another function

```
function request() { 
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(function(data) {
       doLoop(data);
   }); 
}

function doLoop(items){
   /* do stuff here with items */
}

setInterval(function() {
    request()
}, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that, because Ajax is asynchronous ([jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)), everything in the doLoop() is probably executed before your Ajax call is completed. That is why you get an empty element.

What you need to do is to define the two (or more) functions:

```
function request() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getdata.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        doLoop(data);
    });
}

function doLoop(data) {
    var count = data.length;
    // Rest of your code
}
```

And then just call `request()` once to start your ajax call and loop.

Answer (score 0):

since AJAX is asynchronous you need to work with a callback-function here.
i changed your function `request` to take a callback function as parameter:

```
function request(callback) {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getdata.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {

        if(typeof callback === "function") callback(data);

    });
}
```

and i placed an anonymous function inside your request call here as your callback:

```
function doLoop() {
    request(function(data){

        //once you get here, you know for sure that ajax is done

        var items = data; // the returned json data from function request()
        var count = items.length;
        var repeat = count * timeout;

        $(items).each(function(idx, text) {
            $("#text").queue(function(next) {
                $(this).html(text);
                next();
            }).delay(timeout);
        });
    });     
}
```

this anonymous function is called by the `callback(data)` in your request-function. so once you get into the body of this anonymous function, you know for sure that the ajax call is done and you also get your data in the `data` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
var seconds = 6;
var timeout = seconds * 1000;
var items =null;

function request() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getdata.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        items =data;
    });
}

function doLoop() {
    $.when( request()).then( work, fail);
}

function fail(){
    //manage failure
 }


 function work(){
    var count = items.length;
    var repeat = count * timeout;
    $(items).each(function(idx, text) {
        $("#text").queue(function(next) {
            $(this).html(text);
            next();
        }).delay(timeout);
    });
```

}

```
setInterval(function() {
    doLoop();
}, repeat);
```

return data from request and amange it in doLoop.

remembar do add `cache:false` [option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  to ajax call in request to avoid that the results remains in cache.

I've updated my answer with the use of promises